# ViewPager implement in Activity,View pager automatically get one previous and next item data and layout View

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

```
    // Set Adapter
    ViewPagerIndexAdapter = new ViewPagerIndexAdapter(ReadingActivity.this, SubIndexAdapter.indexList, indexID);
    viewpager.setAdapter(viewPagerIndexAdapter);
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(this.indexForReading);
```

I set setCurrentItem item of viewpager it set the next page data when the first time viewpager display on nextActivity.

ViewPager implement in Activity, View pager automatically get one previous and next item data and layout View.

Comment: Viewpager will hold the data of next position once you are at current position.Its the functionality of view pager.

Answer (score 0):

the default value for offscreen page limit is 1, to disable this functionality you can use the following code:

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```